# Tannenbaum paper on constants in ISAs?

Tags: cpu, microprocessor

I see many references to a paper by Andrew Tanenbaum that demonstrated the vast majority of constants would fit into 13-bits, and I *seem* to recall it being in my university text on CPU design. However, I can't find a reference to it. Does anyone have a pointer?

Comment: Looking at a few Google references to this. It seems like everybody knows somebody who thinks Tanembaum wrote it, but nobody has ever seen the original document :)

Comment: Maybe [this list](https://dblp.org/pers/hd/t/Tanenbaum:Andrew_S=) would provide some help.

Comment: For the record, I wrote to Andy and he sent me a much better copy of the paper. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Andrew Tanenbaum wrote two papers about operand encoding, instruction sizes, and the representations of structured programming constructs, which sounds like what you’re looking for: [*Implications of structured programming for machine architecture*](https://doi.org/10.1145/359361.359454) (Communications of the ACM, March 1978) and [*Efficient encoding of machine instructions*](https://doi.org/10.1145/859470.859472) (ACM SIGARCH Computer Architecture News, June 1979).